# Scoped variable is creating a reference instead of new instance

Tags: javascript

Experiencing a weird Javascript bug it'd be great to get some insight to. I've managed to debug it to know what the issue is, I just haven't been able to figure out the **why** yet and a non-hackey way to resolve it.

I'm trying to create a new instance of an array as a variable inside a function, so I can manipulate it without affecting the main array. Instead I'm getting some kind of reference, so doing operations on my new variable `ids` also affects the array that `ids` equals.

I've simplified my code to demonstrate the issue more clearly:

```
var defence = {

    selectedIDs: new Array(),

    toggleTerm: function(term, id) {

        // add to the main array
        this.selectedIDs.push(5);

        // adds to this.selectedIDs
        this.showTweet();

    },

    showTweet: function() {

        // copy the array as a new variable in the scope of the function
        var ids = this.selectedIDs;

        if (ids.length == 1) {
            ids.push(10); // this pushes to 'ids' AND 'this.selectedIDs'
        }
        console.log(this.selectedIDs); // outputs [5, 10]

    }

}
```

**[Also in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BdCKk/1/)**

It's always been my understand that `var ids = this.selectedIDs` would effectively **copy** the contents of `this.selectedIDs` into that new instance - however this doesn't seem to be the case.

Any ideas on why this is happening, and the best way to get around it (beyond manually recreating it through something like a for loop)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's always been my understand that var ids = this.selectedIDs would
>   effectively copy the contents

OK, but your understanding is [wrong](http://brianorndorf.typepad.com/.a/6a00e54ee7b6428833017d3bc8d514970c-800wi).  It's an assignment.

Consider this instead:

```
var ids = this.selectedIDs.slice()
```

Comment: Note that JS has a lot of array-like things that don't necessarily have the full Array API.  E.g. you can't call slice() on the `arguments` object.  You have to do something like `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)`.

Comment: Good point, @broofa -- the most noticeable (to me) example: `arguments`

Comment: `NodeList`s as well (e.g. returned by `document.getElementsByClassName()`)

Answer (score 0):

> It's always been my understand that `var ids = this.selectedIDs` would
>   effectively **copy** the contents of this.selectedIDs into that new
>   instance - however this doesn't seem to be the case.

I don’t know how to describe this except “no, that doesn’t happen at all”. JavaScript isn’t C++; when you assign something to a variable, it is *never* copied. You always get a reference, except in the case of primitives, which are immutable, making the point moot. (Heh.)

You could use `concat`, but if this isn’t the actual situation, there might be something more appropriate.

```
showTweet: function() {
    var ids = this.selectedIDs;

    if (ids.length === 1) {
        ids = ids.concat(10); // Array.prototype.concat returns a new array
    }

    console.log(this.selectedIDs); // outputs [5]
}
```